# ${}$ Projectile motion

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, conventions, projectile

Basically we take the value of acceleration due to gravity as -ve ($-g$),when an object is thrown in the opposite direction of $g$. But in projectile motion the object first opposed the g and travels towards g. So there is need for both +ve and -ve value of g, Then why we are using -g in vertical component throughout to derive equations to describe the the projectile.

Comment: form Newton' second law 

$$m\,\ddot x=0~,m\,\ddot y=-m\,g$$

those are the 2 differential equations for the projectile motion in x-y space

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The sign of acceleration due to gravity is purely based on the coordinate system. If you take vertically downward direction as negative, then the acceleration due to gravity will be *-g*.

Whether the object goes upwards or downwards, it doesn't matter. Gravity always acts downwards, and according to the before mentioned coordinate system, all throughout deriving equations you will use *-g*.

> So there is need for both +ve and -ve value of g.

No there is no such specific need,  if you want to do so then the direction of motion of the object will be your coordinate system, and since the direction of object keeps on changing, your coordinate system keeps on changing.

Comment: But logically we should use both know.

Comment: You can use both, but you will have to keep changing your coordinate systems accordingly.

Comment: Upward motion -g and downmotion +g

Comment: you can do that. the direction of motion of the object will be your coordinate system then, and since the direction of object keeps on changing, your coordinate system keeps on changing. Although, there will be a tendency for you to get confused at some point in calculations, that's why the convention is to just take one coordinate system and follow it throughout solving all your derivations.

Comment: Clear!!!.......

Comment: Though I can still use my way to find :)